# Is there an equivalent in Javascript/Coffeescript/jQuery to Ruby's send?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, coffeescript, metaprogramming

If I have a method name in a string, in Ruby I can use `send` to dynamically dispatch methods, e.g.

```
method_name = "delete"
send method_name
```

I can take advantage of interpolation too:

```
method_name = "add"
send "#{method_name}_task", args
```

I've 2 functions defined in javascript, one to delete, one to update something. A button for each is dynamically added and, at the moment, just the delete method gets bound via `button.on "click"`, e.g.

```
b.on "click", (event) ->
  event.preventDefault() # stop submission via postback
  this_button = $(this)
  task_id = this_button.data("task-id")
  delete_task( task_id, this_button )
  false
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
method_name = "delete"
b.on "click", (event) ->
  event.preventDefault() # stop submission via postback
  this_button = $(this)
  task_id = this_button.data("task-id")
  send "#{method_name}_task", task_id, this_button
  false
```

The only difference between the binding of the 2 functions is this one line. If there's an obvious way, it'd be helpful to cut down on the repetition. I haven't found anything in my searches, so if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you sending to in the coffeescript code? in the ruby examples you have `obj`.

Comment: @Esailija Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'm not using an object in the javascript. Ruby automatically uses self i.e. this, so there's no object needed in the example, I just thought it would be clearer. I'll change it, thanks.

Comment: "Ruby automatically uses self _if no receiver is explicitly given_" I should have written above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a [bracket notation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1)

```
 b.on("click", window[method_name](event))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
method_name = "delete"
obj.send method_name
```

Looks like it would be like this in Javascript:

```
methodName = "delete";
obj[methodName]();
```

---

You always need the `obj` though, so if in ruby `send method_name` is same as `self.send method_name`, then you can use `this[methodName]()`.

Answer (score 3):

If your method was defined in global scope, e.g.

```
function func_delete(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
}
```

just use square brackets notation:

```
var method_name = "func_delete";
window[method_name](arg1, arg2);
```

Otherwise you may use custom object properties in the same way:

```
var methods = {
    func_delete: function() { ... }
};

methods[method_name]();
```